# Eclipse Plugin to Invoke a GUI

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I understand the process of creating Eclipse plugins and adding buttons or menu items to Eclipse.
I would like to know how to create an Eclipse Plugin which should add a button to the eclipse menu and that button must invoke a GUI. How do I proceed with that?

The GUI will be a form where the user needs to select a bunch of options. How do I create this GUI form within a custom Eclipse plugin??

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of information already out there as long as you search using the [correct names](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/nav/0_2). Start with a [simple plug-in](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/firstplugin.htm?cp=2_0_2) then work your way up to creating [Wizards](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/dialogs_wizards.htm?cp=2_0_5_3).